# Neomodel 4.0 Bolt URI for multiple databases

Tags: python, neo4j, bolt, neomodel

I recently upgraded my Neo4j database from 3.5 to 4.1 and also the neomodel package. I have created multiple databases on the server. Whenever I am running a query, it always runs on a specific database. What do I need to do to target a different database through bolt URI programmatically?

Comment: Are you talking about on an adhoc basisc? I.E being able to switch the connection as you require it within the same application?

Comment: @SteveMapes Exactly! I need to switch databases dynamically. Is there a way to do that or do I need to create a separate server for each database? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this. At the moment no Neomodel only supports querying one database. There is an open request for this within their issue tracker - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/issues/526. This is because config.DATABASE_URL is set once, or it was on the last version I used